# How to pass model validations to ModelSerializer when using source parameter?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In my serializer I have my columns from model changed to different names because I need them that way in API.

*model*:

```
class User(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
   telephone_number = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True, blank=True)
```

*serializer*:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   phoneNumber = serializers.CharField(source='telephone_number')
   class Meta:
      model = User
      fields = ('name', 'telephone_number')
```

But when I do it then serializer doesn't take into account validations given set in model.

```
>>> serializer = UserSerializer()
>>> print(repr(serializer))
UserSerializer():
    name = CharField(allow_null=True, max_length=50, required=False)
    phoneNumber = CharField(source='telephone_number') <- no max_length here
```

How to invoke these validations without need to duplicate them into serializer? (of course my models are considerably bigger that's why i'm asking)

Comment: You can use the `validators` argument of the serializer fields. This argument allows you to add the same validators that you have defined in the model field to the serializer field. I dumped the code [here](https://www.codedump.xyz/py/ZBGlyGYFcr_WVVoO) at codedump.xyz see if that's what you need and tell me.

Comment: @SunderamDubey no, that's the whole idea behind this question - I wanna validations from model to automatically transfer to fields with custom names in serializer. Like they do for fields with default name (same as in the model)

Comment: I understand now. In that case, you can use the `validators` parameter in the `serializers.CharField` definition to reference the validators defined in the corresponding model field. Now see the code [here](https://www.codedump.xyz/py/ZBGoYti5SxalAeWi) at codedump.xyz and tell me. Also note that this assumes that you have defined validators on your model field, otherwise you'll get an `AttributeError`.

Comment: @SunderamDubey I gave you upvote for effort, because that's some way to do it, but as you can see in my post, I have no validators defined. So while this will work I need to change my models classes for this approach. I still hope there's simpler way to do it

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a new field yourself in the serializer body, it understands that you want to override the field's original definition completely and use whatever attributes you used inside `serializers.CharField()`. Using `source` does not copy all other attributes automatically like `max_length`.

One solution is to use `to_internal_value` as a workaround to rename the field without having to copy all its model attributes to the serializer field.

```py
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
      model = User
      fields = ('name', 'telephone_number')
   
   def to_internal_value(self, data):
      data["telephone_number"] = data["phoneNumber"]
      return super().to_internal_value(data)
```

This way you can accept data to the serializer using `phoneNumber` as a field name.